# Github Desktop Commit to master button greyed out if more than one change slected

Tags: github, git-commit, github-desktop

I have a lot of stuff that I want to add to github so I have the desktop version to make local changes. I add everything I have and before I can push it I have to commit to master, problem is I have 1100 changes and I can only commit one at a time if more than one is selected with pretty much any combination of different files but the button remains greyed out if I have more than 1 file selected.

Comment: I have the same issue.